# Can I quit my job in Dubai and go to my home country?

Tags: job-hunting, career

I have been working for a company for the last 5 months. Can I quit this job and go to my home country? As I want to leave Dubai and go to my country. I have heard that, I have to pay visa fees or 1.5 month salary to company, is it true?

Comment: @GaLa Thanks for edit. I am not pro in English :)

Comment: No problem, I think your question is fine, hopefully someone can help.

Comment: AFAIK, Saudi Arabia and Quatar have exit visas, but the UAE do not so if you have a passport, you could probably just leave the country. But you might get problems if you want to come back to Dubai in the future. Not an authoritative source by any means but [this forum](http://www.expatforum.com/expats/dubai-expat-forum-expats-living-dubai/84919-dubai-exit-visa.html) might be useful.

Comment: What does your employment contract have to say on the matter?

Comment: @GaLa My passport is with my company. And i don't want to run away without inform to company. I want to leave as legal.

Comment: @Gagravarr In my Labor contract there mentioned Unlimited contract of terms.

Comment: Obviously, you have every right to quit your job at the agreed notice. An unlimited contract means there is no fixed end date, not that you have to stay for the rest of your life. Look at the notice period in your contract. If none specified, the default according to UAE law is apparently 30 days. Demand your passport back. Consult with a lawyer if the company is giving you a hard time leaving. In the future, never hand over your passport. Don't accept a job with a company that requires you to do so.

Comment: Thank you guys for your post here to help me. After your guide i submit my resignation to company and they have not ask me for any money or etc. I will leave Dubai on 30 Aug 2014. Let see maybe they can ask when i am leaving. Thanks again.

Comment: @RaviDesai can you tell if you had to pay any amount to employer ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad No, I didn't pay. I think the employer should not ask employees to pay the fees.

Answer (score 4):

Your passport is with your company? Is that even legal? I'm not sure it is.

I would recommend that you contact the consulate of your country of citizenship in Dubai. They will speak your language, they will understand your situation, and they should be able to help.

Comment: It's quite common in this part of the world, I think. Exit visas (where they exist) even make sure that getting a new passport from the consulate is not enough to circumvent the system. In any case, this sounds more like a comment than a real answer and wouldn't address the OP's issue as he wants to leave in good terms with his employer and the local government.

Comment: @Greg In Dubai almost all company kept passport of employee as i have heard. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Interesting. My passport says it "cannot be given, or accepted as a security, pledge, or deposit". I guess things are different in your part of the world. Hope you find a solution.

Comment: @Greg, this is very common for immigrants from less developed countries. It is usually illegal and intended as a form of leverage to screw over workers who may not know they have a choice. It is not common for folks from developed countries (though I have heard of it happening to English teachers in South Korea)